# Angular2 unit tests with Karma and PhantomJs failed on CI

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, google-chrome-headless

I successfully run my angular2 units tests on my local machine (windows 7) with Karma and Chrome (and even Chrome_Headless).

But when I try to run theses tests with PhantomJs They both failed on my local machine and on my Jenkins CI (CentOs). I have 11 failed tests and 85 passed and I don't understand why.

The error message of all failed tests look like:

```js
[1A[2KPhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) Apptopbar Inputs shoud be properly initialize FAILED
 Error: Error in ./Apptopbar class Apptopbar - inline template:44:66 caused by: Attempted to assign to readonly property. in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts (line 131597)
 setElementProperty@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:129737:59 <- webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/debug/debug_renderer.js:171:25
 setElementProperty@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:129741:42 <- webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/debug/debug_renderer.js:175:0
 detectChangesInternal
 detectChanges@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:131372:35 <- webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:425:0
 detectChanges@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:131567:48 <- webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:620:0
 internalDetectChanges@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:131357:31 <- webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:410:0
 detectChangesInternal
 detectChanges@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:131372:35 <- webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:425:0
 detectChanges@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:131567:48 <- webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:620:0
 detectChanges@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:86432:33 <- webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view_ref.js:170:0
 _tick@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:12449:49 <- webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:196:0
 /var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:12463:58 <- webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:210:45
 invoke@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/polyfills.ts:2204:31 <- webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:334:0
 onInvoke@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:192941:45 <- webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0
 invoke@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/polyfills.ts:2203:40 <- webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:333:0
 onInvoke@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:41162:43 <- webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone.js:273:0
 invoke@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/polyfills.ts:2203:40 <- webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:333:0
 run@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/polyfills.ts:1996:49 <- webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:126:0
 run@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:41031:65 <- webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone.js:142:42
 detectChanges@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:12463:32 <- webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:210:0
 /var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:195771:30 <- webpack:///src/test/components/top-bar.component.spec.ts:72:25
 invoke@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/polyfills.ts:2204:31 <- webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:334:0
 onInvoke@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:192941:45 <- webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0
 invoke@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/polyfills.ts:2203:40 <- webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:333:0
 run@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/polyfills.ts:1996:49 <- webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:126:0
 /var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:192641:37 <- webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:104:0
 /var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:1962:19 <- webpack:///~/moment/moment.js:1421:0
 /var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:1905:11 <- null:0:0
 /var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:12349:35 <- webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:96:0
 invoke@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/polyfills.ts:2204:31 <- webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:334:0
 onInvoke@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:192236:45 <- webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:49:0
 onInvoke@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:192938:47 <- webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:76:0
 invoke@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/polyfills.ts:2203:40 <- webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:333:0
 run@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/polyfills.ts:1996:49 <- webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:126:0
 /var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:12344:32 <- webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:91:0
 /var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/test.ts:192225:46 <- webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:38:0
 invokeTask@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/polyfills.ts:2237:36 <- webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:367:0
 runTask@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/polyfills.ts:2036:57 <- webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:166:0
 invoke@/var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/polyfills.ts:2290:45 <- webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:420:0
 /var/jenkins_home/workspace/AttestationCockpitGUI_Guerrit/src/polyfills.ts:3451:34 <- webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1581:0
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 96 of 99 (7 FAILED) (0 secs / 10.446 secs)
[1A[2KLOG: 'WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value [object Object] (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).'
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 96 of 99 (7 FAILED) (0 secs / 10.446 secs)
[1A[2KLOG: 'WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value [object Object] (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).'
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 96 of 99 (7 FAILED) (0 secs / 10.446 secs)
```

I see a lot of similar posts on Github (issues with angular-mocks) but the workaround doesn't work for me

Edit: My Jenkins CI is running on a docker container. 
Here is my test.js file

```js
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

// Unfortunately there's no typing for the `__karma__` variable. Just declare it as any.
declare var __karma__: any;
declare var require: any;

// Prevent Karma from running prematurely.
__karma__.loaded = function () {};

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./test/', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
// Finally, start Karma to run the tests.
__karma__.start();
```

And here is the relevant parts of my karma config:

```js
      port: 9876,
      colors: true,
      logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
      autoWatch: false,
      concurrency: Infinity,
      customLaunchers: {
        'PhantomJS_custom': {
          base: 'PhantomJS',
          options: {
            windowName: 'my-window',
            settings: {
              webSecurityEnabled: false
            },
          },
          flags: ['--load-images=true'],
          debug: true
        },
        ChromeHeadless: {
          base: 'Chrome',
          flags: [
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--headless',
            '--disable-gpu',
            // Without a remote debugging port, Google Chrome exits immediately.
            '--remote-debugging-port=9222',
          ],
        }
      },
      phantomjsLauncher: {
        // Have phantomjs exit if a ResourceError is encountered (useful if karma exits without killing phantom) 
        exitOnResourceError: true
      },
      browsers: [ 'ChromeHeadless'],
      singleRun: true,
      browserNoActivityTimeout: 500000
    });
```

I even try using puppeteer but it still doesn't work on my CI.

Comment: Could you pust the code of that `test.ts` file ?

Comment: @trichetriche  I've edited my post with the test.ts